# background email sending in ionic cordova appllication

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, ngcordova

I am working on an Android application (with ionic and cordova) which sends emergency message to a list of contacts when user clicks on **panic** button, I also want to send email to listed email addresses without opening composer or my-email application. i.e. I want to do it on background. How I can achieve my requirement,

Answer (score 3):

You should create a backend with a rest API that handles the emails. Then your app will call the endpoint when it needs to send emails. You could also use something like mailgun or other email service.